# NIOCore.ChannelError.connectTimeout(NIOCore.TimeAmount(nanoseconds: 10000000000))

Tags: vapor

My project with Swift Vapor was working well, and one day, I started getting this warning in the Xcode console and web browser of my development computer. On the server side, the deployed code works well. The only thing I know I have changed is the Wi-Fi.

Web browser:

```
{"error":true,"reason":"connectTimeout(NIOCore.TimeAmount(nanoseconds: 10000000000))"}
```

Xcode console:

```
[ NOTICE ] Server starting on http://127.0.0.1:8080
[ INFO ] GET / [request-id: 25226CA3-7D45-4765-84CA-E93FCB92FFCA]
[ INFO ] GET / [request-id: 5D1E6E99-0E7A-4449-BF4A-450C411743F7]
[ WARNING ] NIOCore.ChannelError.connectTimeout(NIOCore.TimeAmount(nanoseconds: 10000000000))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to connect to a database (most likely, could be another external service) and you either have no route to that service or your IP address is getting blocked by a firewall. Make sure you can connect to the service from your machine

Comment: yes, it was a problem with my machine ip which was not whitelisted in my database.